# Обращение на "вы"

Tags: лексика

Стало интересно: а когда и как появилось обращение на "вы"? Насколько я знаю, в древних языках такого обращения не было. Насколько это обращение древнее?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Если позволите кратко и без подтверждающих ссылок, то дело обстоит так.
Вежливая форма обращения в том или ином виде существовала во множестве языков, едва ли не во всех, кроме архаичных.

А вот использование формы множественного числа как формы вежливого обращения, это другое.

Первое появление отмечено в латыни, но системного употребления она не получила.

Возможно, где-то это было и раньше, но современные европейские языки унаследовали это от французского, где такая форма появилась, если не ошибаюсь, в эпоху абсолютизма, веке в  XVI-XVII.

При этом надо иметь в виду, что отнюдь не все, даже европейские, языки его позаимствовали. В немецком, например, другая схема.

Что касается русского, то завез вежливое обращение, конечно, Петр из голландского (там эта форма близка к английскому), но распространения она сразу не получила, даже будучи закрепленной в "табели о рангах". Поэтому её реальное появление связывают больше с екатерининской эпохой.

Вот кое-что по теме.
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B

Answer (score 1):

Есть версия, что на "вы" впервые стали обращаться к римским консулам, которых, как известно, было двое. Каждый мог наложить вето на любое решение, следовательно, если решение было всё же принято, согласны с ним были оба, то есть действовали заодно, как один человек.

Очевидно, обращение "вы" должно обозначать, что лицо, к которому обращаются, для говорящего столь же значимо, как римский консул.)))